# Habilitar e desabilitar JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Tenho dois `JButton` na minha janela, `btnCalcular` e `btnConfirmar`.
O `btnCalcular` calcula alguns valores da janela, e o `btnConfirmar` pega esses valores e armazenam em outro lugar. A questão é que **obrigatóriamente** eu quero deixar o `btnConfirmar` desativado enquanto o outro botão não for clicado, para ele não guardar valores nulos.

Já tentei o `while (btnCalcular.getClickCount() > 0){...}` mas a IDE não reconheceu, mesmo eu colocando essa condição dentro de um dos métodos de um `MouseListener`.
Como fazer isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inicie o `btnConfirmar` na sua janela como desativado:

```
btnConfirmar.setEnabled(false);
```

Depois, ative-o dentro do `actionPerformed` do outro botão, conforme a necessidade:

```
    btnCalcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             //ative ele assim que o botão for clicado
             btnConfirmar.setEnabled(true);             
        }
    });
```